# Write multiple Avro files from pyspark to the same directory

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hdfs, avro

I'm trying to write out dataframe as Avro files from PySpark dataframe to the path `/my/path/` to HDFS,  and partition by the col 'partition', so under `/my/path/` , there should be the following sub directory structures

```
partition= 20230101
partition= 20230102
....
```

Under these sub directories, there should be the avro files. I'm trying to use

```
df1.select("partition","name","id").write.partitionBy("partition").format("avro").save("/my/path/")
```

It succeed the first time with , but when I tried to write another df with a new partition, it failed with error : path /my/path/ already exist. How should I achieve this? Many thanks for your help. The df format is as below:

```
partition  name   id 
20230101.   aa.   10 ---this row is the content in the first df
20230102.   bb.   20 ---this row is the content in the second df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change the [SaveMode](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/index.html?org/apache/spark/sql/SaveMode.html).
By default save mode is `ErrorIfExists`, so you are getting an error.
Change it to append mode.

```
df1.select("partition","name","id") \
  .write.mode("append").format("avro")\
  .partitionBy("partition").save("/my/path/")
```